# Block OUTGOING port 25 traffic from specific IPs on openvz host

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, openvz

I have a server running CentOS 5.5 and acting as an OpenVZ host.  One of the containers has been sending out spam and I need to block his ability to connect to outbound port 25.  I've looked at http://wiki.openvz.org/Setting_up_an_iptables_firewall, but this setup is to prevent INCOMING traffic and I have not found a working IPTABLES rule that prevented a specific IP address from connecting to an OUTBOUND port.

I've tried:
`iptables -I OUTPUT --source [CONTAINER_IP] --protocol tcp --destination-port 25 -j DROP`

but that does not appear to actually block it.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OUTPUT table is used for sending traffic originating from the host.  With Virtualization I'm not sure if the traffic uses the OUTPUT chain, or as it's being routed from a virtual device *through* the host, it may use the FORWARD chain instead.  Try replacing OUTPUT with FORWARD in your rule.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle Smith's answer is correct with small notice: this rule must be placed defore any other FORWARD rules:

> iptables -L
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
>
> target     prot opt source               destination
>
> DROP       tcp  --  [CONTAINER_IP]  anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
>
> RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>
> /etc/sysconfig/iptables
>
> :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
>
> :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
>
> :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
>
> :RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
>
> /* Block outgoing 25 port for containers */
>
> -A FORWARD -p tcp --destination-port 25 -s [CONTAINER_IP] -j DROP
>
> /* Main config */
>
> -A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
>
> -A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT

Comment: More specifically it needs to be placed before any DROP rules that would block it.